# Quick question about trigonometric substitution $\int\frac{u+5}{u^2+9}du$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate this integral::

$$\int\frac{u+5}{u^2+9}du$$

which is a part of:

$$\int\frac{e^x}{(e^x-5)(e^{2x}+9)}dx$$

The part I posted is the only one giving me a wrong answer. I am using trigonometric substitution, but I can't see the error I've made so I'd like someone to point out what's wrong with my method:

Using $u=3\tan\theta$

$$\int\frac{u+5}{u^2+9}du$$ 
$$\int\frac{(3\tan\theta+5)(3\sec^2\theta)}{9\tan^2+9}d\theta$$
$$\int\frac{(3\tan\theta+5)(3\sec^2\theta)}{9\sec^2\theta}d\theta$$
$$\frac{1}{3}\int(3\tan\theta+5)d\theta$$
$$\int(\tan\theta)d\theta +\frac{5}{3}\int(d\theta)$$
$$\log|\sec\theta| + \frac{5}{3}\arctan\frac{u}{3}$$
$$\log|\frac{\sqrt{u^2+9}}{3}| + \frac{5}{3}\arctan\frac{u}{3}$$

Apparently, the logarithm is incorrect.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: if you used the substitution $u=e^x$, then your new integral in terms of $u$ is incorrect. It should be integral of $\frac{1}{(u-5)(u^2+9)}$

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look. Since I am just learning trigonometric substitution is the method I posted above correct?

Comment: yeap, it is correct for your integral !

Comment: @Jane Alright that's great. I split the fraction in two when first calculating the integral, but that's not important. I am glad my method is correct for trig substitution.

Comment: That's great! Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is correct and can be simplified as $\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(u^{2}+9\right)+\frac{5}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{3}\right)+c$, with the constant $c$ different from yours.

Comment: "Apparently, the logarithm is incorrect." Other methods proposed herein show $\frac12\ln(u^2+9)$ is in any antiderivative. If you compare your work to some other source's statement of an antiderivative, you need only worry about the integration constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Split this into two integrals.
$$\int\frac u{u^2+9}du+5\int\frac{du}{u^2+9}$$

The first doesn't require trig substitution, just $u$-substitution.  Use trig substitution on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{u+5}{u^{2}+9}du\\
u=3v\Rightarrow du=3dv\\
\int\frac{u+5}{u^{2}+9}du=\int\frac{3v+5}{9v^{2}+9}3dv=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2vdv}{v^{2}+1}+\frac{15}{9}\int\frac{dv}{v^{2}+1}\\
\int\frac{u+5}{u^{2}+9}du=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{u^{2}}{9}+1)+\frac{5}{3}\arctan(\frac{u}{9})+c$$